# C# using a range of indexes in an if statment

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I have this simple code:

```
if(number == arrayOfNumbers[1]){
//some code
}
```

And I want the code to be like this:

```
if(number == arrayOfNumbers[index>=1  /*any index that is equal or bigger than one*/]{
//some code
}
```

does this kind of functions exist? if not can you tell me the simplest way to write such a statement? also I don't mind coverting the array to a list if such a funciton exists for a list. Can sombody help? thank you

EDIT: I have seen the List.Any() method. but it does not help me. I want to search all the numbers starting from index 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this

```
if (arrayOfNumbers.Select((i, x) => new { i, x }).Any(x => x.i > 1 && x.x == number))
{
    // some code
}
```

The `Select` creates an anonymous object for each entry in the list that includes the entry itself and its index. The `Any` will return `true` if there is an entry equal to your number that is at an index 2 or greater.

or

```
if (arrayOfNumbers.Skip(1).Any(x => x == number))
```

Comment: Or `collectionOfNumbers.Select((i, x) => i > 1 && x == number).Contains(true)` which avoids the need to build throw-away `{ i, x }` objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes. Good improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the last index of number and check if it is > 0 :

```
if (Array.LastIndexOf(arrayOfNumbers, number) > 0) {
```

Or search for number starting from index 1 :

```
if (Array.IndexOf(arrayOfNumbers, number, 1) >= 0) {
```

Comment: This one's particularly useful because, unlike the LINQ `Select` or `Skip`+`Any`, this gives you the index where the item was found.